# A way to simplify an expression so it's easier to use it for computation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to simplify an expression so that it's easy to use it in a program?

For example:

```
Return[3(x+Sqrt[y])^2+9(x+Sqrt[y])]
```

Would become:

```
temp1=x+Sqrt[y]; Return[3 temp1^2+9 temp1]
```

Basically if the same expression appears multiple times in a larger expression, is there a way to automatically extract it so that it only has to be calculated once?

Comment: It's certainly possible depending on the depth you're willing to go down to. Gathering things is easy with Cases. Replacing is easy with ReplaceAll.

Comment: I'm hoping for a way to do it that'll apply to most cases in an automated way, and will recognize equivalent expressions (like Simplify would)

Comment: You do not need to use the `Return` function. Just evaluate the input cell and the result will be shown in an output cell.